# Read file with Java

Tags: java, nio

I want to read SSL Certificate file with java from the location:

```
 URL url = TestSSLPacketChannel.class.getResource("/client.public");
    Path resPath = Paths.get(url.toURI());
    String file = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resPath), "UTF8");
```

This code successfully finds the file located at `src\test\resources` but when I send the file to this Java method:

```
new FileInputStream(SSL_Cert);
```

I get exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path`

Unfortunately I can;t change the method `new FileInputStream(SSL_Cert);` because I will break the code logic.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I see no code that explains what `SSL_Cert` is or what value it might hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the whole file path.
"C:\User\Folder\file..."

Comment: Sometimes you also need to add escape characters to the path.